# Group homomorphisms $S_3\to\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Knowing that $S_3=\{\text{id},\sigma,\sigma^2,\tau,\tau\circ\sigma,\tau\circ\sigma^2\}$ ($\tau=(1 2), \sigma=(123)$), why does a group homomorphism $f:S_3\to\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ satisfy $f(a)=0$ for all $a\in S_3$ such that $a^2\neq e$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $S_3$, for every element $a$ with $a^2\ne e$, we have $a^3=e$. If we map $a$ to $1$ instead of $0$, this creates a problem, because $1+1+1\ne 0$ in $\Bbb Z / 2\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 2):

The order of an element $a\in S_3$ divides $6$, but as $S_3$ is not cyclic, we must have all elements being of order $1$, $2$, or $3$. If $a^2\neq e$, what must the order of $a$ be? Now use the fact that the order of $f(a)$ must divide the order of $a$.

Answer (score 2):

If $a^2\neq e,$ then the order of $a$ must be 3. The order of $f(a)$ must then divide 3, but it must also divide 2 (as element of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$). Thus, $f(a)$ must have order 1.